# New to MySQLi, Error on UPDATE Query?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm having a little bit of an issue trying to resolve this query, this is a script that is 'required' on the page if the submit button is clicked after form entry. The page already has the $connection variable set, and the values are echoing correctly, though I still get the "error" message echoed to me during the second nested 'IF' statement. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
<?php
if ($_POST['firstname'] != "" && $_POST['lastname'] != "" && $_POST['email'] != "" && $_POST['position'] != "" && $_POST['building'] != "") {
    $iserid = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['userid']);
    $fname_input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']);
    $lname_input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']);
    $fullname_input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']) . " " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']);
    $email_input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $position_input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['position']);
    $building_input = 1;

    $update = $connection->prepare("UPDATE user SET first = ?, last = ?, full = ?, email = ?, position = ?, building = ? WHERE id =  ?") or trigger_error($connection->error);
    $update->bind_param("ssssssi",$fname_input, $lname_input, $fullname_input, $email_input, $position_input, $building_input, $userid);

    if ($update->execute) {
        echo "success";
        $update->close();
    } else {
        echo "fail";
        $update->close();
    }

} else {
    $error = "One or more of your fields was left blank. Please press back on you browser toolbar and try again or click here to close this message.";
}
?>
```

Comment: There are lots of reasons for this to fail.  You should be getting something in the PHP log files.

Comment: Are all your form fields correct with the correct `name=` attributes?  (Side note - you should not store values in the database with `htmlspecialchars()`. That is an _output_ sanitization method, and it may cause you future problems when trying to search your tables if they data has been modified.

Comment: I think is `$update->execute()` you forgot `()`

Comment: @MateiMihai - Please submit this as an answer so I can give you kudos, you saved me a lot of frustration! It's always the small things that drive you crazy, eh? Thank you so much.

Comment: $update->execute should be $update->execute().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if($update->execute)
```

with

```
if($update->execute())
```